# Maximo special Query for PMs without asset

Tags: mysql, sql, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I need a query for Maximo to select PMs without asset including PMs that have route and route has no asset.

Comment: Provide table structure / sample data and expected output. Also include what you have done till now.

Answer (score 0):

In GoTo-> Platform Configuration ->Database Configuration you can search for PM object, click on tab 'Relationship' and search for relationship with object Routes. You can use this relationship in your SQL query in order to customize it futher (no assets).

If you want to know what is the relationship between Routes and Assets do the same thing to object Routes as I described for PM object below: search for object Routes, click on tab 'Relationship' and see what relationship does it use with assets.